# Datagrid Filter using textbox

Tags: vb.net

Goodday!
i'm Adding a textbox for filtering name,lastnames and etc.
but i can only filter one data.

here's the code:

```vb
Private Sub Filter_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles filter.TextChanged
        'Dim command As New MySqlCommand("SELECT * FROM `employee` WHERE CONCAT('Firstname','Lastname') like '%" & filter.Text & "%'")
        Dim conenc As New MySqlConnection
        conenc.ConnectionString = ("host=127.0.0.1; user=root; database=library")
        Dim tablee As New DataTable()
        Try
            conenc.Open()
            Dim adapter As New MySqlDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM library.employee WHERE Firstname like '%" & filter.Text & "%'", conenc)
            adapter.Fill(tablee)
            emplo.DataSource = tablee
            conenc.Close()

        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox(ex.Message)
        Finally
            conenc.Dispose()

        End Try
```

in the line :

Dim adapter As New MySqlDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM library.employee WHERE **Firstname** like '%" & filter.Text & "%'", conenc)

i would like to add multiple values like the lastname, middle name.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set "And" as an unused string variable once the first filter is set, if selecting another filter Concatenate the "And "  before the SQL for that filter. I hope that makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try it more like this (using params)

```
    Dim TxBoxSearch As New TextBox
    Dim conenc As New SqlConnection
    Dim CmdEmployee As New SqlCommand("SELECT *, Firstname + Lastname AS FullName 
                                        FROM library.employee WHERE FullName like '%@SearchString%'", conenc)
    With CmdEmployee
        .Parameters.AddWithValue("@SearchString", TxBoxSearch.Text)
    End With
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should try this code, just add the second condition for the last name in your code like this:

```
Dim adapter As New MySqlDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM library.employee WHERE Firstname like '%" & filter.Text & "%' and Lastname like '%" & filter2.Text & "%'", conenc)
```

I Hope it helps you ,,, 
^_^